# How to change standard Yii2 app name ("My Application")?

Tags: yii2

I've tried to search the information according to this, but couldn't find any useful ones.. I just created `email sending` in Yii2 and the email sends as a "My Application", I guess it's because standard `Yii::$app->name` is like that. Could someone tell me how to change it?

Comment: I understand you, you can not find any place where this var is setted, as you could expect it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yii::$app->name value is assigned in your application config

You can change the id and name attribute in your config file

```
'id' => 'your-applicatio-id',
'name' => 'Your application Name',
```

these attributesa are store in different file depend by the template you are using

in basic templae you can set these values  in

yourapp/confi/web.php

```
 $params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

 $config = [
    'id' => 'your-id',
    'name' => 'Your Name',
     ......
```

in advanced  template you can set these values  in

```
 backend/config/main.php
```

and in

```
 frontend/config/main.php
```

You can use it in common config file too
     common/config/main.php

Comment: one must note that in config directory if main.php is unavailable then we can add these attributes in web.php too